# AS2(!) : best crossbrowser way of calling javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, actionscript-2

I have a AS2 project here that makes some troubles on certain browsers.

Can someone tell me, what's the most crossbrowser compatible way to call javascript functions out of a AS2 project (compiled for Flashplayer 8)?

GetURL or ExternalInterface.call?

What to pay attention to?

Sorry if the question is somewhat ambiguous, but i don't want to track a specific bug, just to find another one appearing with some other browser then.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've used both without any issues in a wide range of browsers. My personal preference is for ExternalInterface if the user's Flash Player version is up to it. Because of the 'callback' functionality it can also be used more flexibly.